# PHP Loader needs to be installed. This is a widely used PHP extension for running ionCube protected PHP code, website security and malware blocking

Tags: php, wampserver

estoy usando una herramienta para generar aplicaciones en php, con un servidor web WampSERVER, pero me pide que instale el módulo php cloud,  en mi pc tengo php 7.3.12  ya hice lo que dice la documentación pero  me sigue generando este inconveninte.

PHP Loader needs to be installed. This is a widely used PHP extension for running ionCube protected PHP code, website security and malware blocking

En la ruta php.ini:
zend_extension="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.12/ext/ioncube_loader_win_7.3.dll"

Comment: Estas seguro que [bajaste la versión correcta](https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php)? Reiniciaste el apache? Comprobaste en el `php_info()` que este activa?

Comment: Pues creo que sí, descargué la Windows VC15 (64 bits) pues porque este trae el dll  ioncube_loader_win_7.3.dll, ya que yo tengo PHP 7.3.12 creo que es la correcta, verdad ??